# I'm facing this error "text string must be rendered within a text component"

Tags: react-native

**Title**: "React Native: Error "Text strings must be rendered within a  component""

**Problem Statement**: I'm working on a React Native app, and I'm encountering the error message "Text strings must be rendered within a  component." I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

**Platform and Dependencies**: I'm using React Native with the following dependencies: [list your dependencies here].

**Error Message**: The error occurs in the `todoApp` component, and it points to the line where I render text within a `<Text>` component.

**Description of the Issue**: I have a `todoApp` component that's supposed to display a list of items, but when I add items, I receive the error mentioned above.

**Steps Taken**: I've checked the usage of `<Text>` components, and it seems to be correct. I've also checked for stray text elements outside of `<Text>` components.

**Expected vs. Actual Behavior**: I expect the app to display a list of items, but it's giving an error instead.

**Code Snippets**:

Here is the relevant part of my code:

```
import { TextInput, View, Button, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";
import { useState } from "react";

export default function todoApp() {
  const [inputText, setInputText] = useState("");
  const [itemText, setItemText] = useState([]);

  function toDoText(text) {
    setInputText(text);
  }

  function addText() {
    if (inputText !== "") {
      setItemText([...itemText, inputText]);
    }
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.heading}>
        <Text>Simple ToDo App</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.AddItem}>
        <TextInput
          placeholder="Enter item"
          style={styles.textInput}
          onChangeText={toDoText}
        ></TextInput>
        <Button title="Add item" onPress={addText}></Button>
      </View>
      <View>
        {itemText.map((item) => (
          <Text key={item} style={styles.Viewitem}>
            {item}
          </Text>
        ))}
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    padding: 20,
  },
  heading: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    marginBottom: 15,
    padding: 5,
  },
  AddItem: {
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: 'space-between',
  },
  textInput: {
    borderTopWidth: 1,
    borderColor: 'whitesmoke',
    width: '75%',
    marginRight: 10,
    padding: 5,
  },
  Viewitem: {
    marginTop: 20,
    borderWidth: 1,
    padding: 10,
    borderColor: 'whitesmoke',
  },
});
```

Comment: your code is already working